# Google Analytics - Is there a way to import Universal Analytics property data into Google Analytics 4 property

Tags: google-analytics, migration, universal-analytics, google-analytics-4

All these days for our company website we are using Google Analytics' Universal Analytics property for tracking and analyzing the data.

Since Google Analytics GA4 has lot of improved and new tracking/ options - we would like to migrate to GA4 analytics.
If I create a new GA4 analytics property , then form the day of creating and injection into my code, GA4 tracking will happen.

But we want to analyze the existing data tracked in Universal Analytics, in the new GA4 property. Is that even possible ?

Can we migrate/ import the data or something similar, so that the data collected under Universal Analytics is not lost and can be viewed/ analyzed in the new GA4 property ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to migrate historical data from Universal Analytics (UA) to Google Analytics 4 (GA4). When you migrate, you can avoid data loss by dual-tagging. That is include both GA4 tags and UA tags in your site going forward.

That way your data will continue to be logged in UA and you can compare historical data against fresh data. You will be able to use the analysis tools in GA4 only against fresh data from when you implement GA4.

Reference: [Will I Lose Data Moving from Universal Analytics to Google Analytics 4?](https://infotrust.com/articles/ua-ga4-dual-tagging/)

---

However on July 1, 2023 [universal analytics will no longer be tracked](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/11583528?hl=en). Historical data will be available for only six months. During this time, you can export your historical reports. There will be no automatic way to compare it to new data.

Comment: Exactly @Stephen, there is no way to migrate old data but one should go with dual-tagging, I've done this in some of the sites. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think this is kind a bummer. Anybody knows the explanation for this? I guess there could be both an official explanation and a unofficial one.